# Pontrjagin dual of modules

Tags: homological-algebra, modules, injective-modules, pontrjagin-duality

I am not sure whether this question is appropriate to appear here. If not, I apologize for that.

Given an $R$-module $M$, we define its Pontrjagin dual as $M^{\ast}=Hom_{\mathbb{Z}}(M, \mathbb{Q/Z})$. I have already proved that $M$ is a flat module iff $M^{\ast}$ is an injective module. Now I am stucked in proving the following two conclusions. If anyone can help me out, thanks a lot.

(1) The natural map $M \rightarrow M^{\ast \ast}$ is injective, which may not be an isomorphism.

(2) Every flat $R$-module is a filtered colimit of free $R$-module.

Comment: The second is Lazard's theorem, which could be found in Eisenbud's book on commutative algebra.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure either that the question is appropriate for MO, but this is too long for a comment.

(1): Note that this is just a question about $\mathbb{Z}$-modules. You have to prove that given $m\neq 0\in M$, there exists $\,\ell\,$ in $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M, \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}) $ with $\ell(m)\neq 0$. Consider the submodule $\mathbb{Z}m\subset M$ generated by $m$. It is cyclic, hence admits a nonzero map to $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. Since $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is injective, this maps extends to the required $\ell$.

(2) is a highly nontrivial result. You can find a proof in Lam's *Lectures on Modules
and Rings*, Thm. 4.34.